# how to append url params by default forcefully in magento2

Tags: magento2, url, plugin, dispatch

I want to add current customer session custom field to the every category url.

lets say if user typed in the  browser http://test.html , this should forcefully change to http://test.html?customer_number=1234.

lets say url is http://test.html?color=red ,this should forcefully change to http://test.html?color=red&&customer_number=1234

Comment: you can do that by creating a custom router that checks for the parameter `customer_number`. if it's not set, set it and redirect to the new url: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/routing.html#custom-routers. But I have a feeling you're doing something wrong. If you want customer specific content, use the session to do that not GET params

Comment: @marius some skus i need to display specific  customers only, some skus i need to display for all the customers. product level I created customer_number attribute. basically I need to add forcefully this customer_number as filter to all categories

Comment: that's what I thought. you should do this based on the session information not trying to enforce a get parameter for all urls. What happens if the customer changes that parameter manually?

Comment: even if they change, we should not allow ,we need to check current customer session field

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, and it's required because of Varnish.